# FetchError: request to https://discord.com/api/v7/gateway/bot failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Full error message:

```
(node:4559) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: request to https://discord.com/api/v7/gateway/bot failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at RequestHandler.execute (/Users/myUser/KickerBot/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:93:15)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
(node:4559) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:4559) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am trying to learn how to make a discord bot, and I have followed the guide itself pretty much by the letter, except for my own functions. I restarted my computer to update the software (I'm using a Mac) and when I tried to start the bot through the terminal it threw the error. I've re-changed the token to see if it was outdated and I've updated the npms thinking that maybe they were just messed up from the update.

I'm not very familiar with Promises and have no idea why it says it has an unhandled one, especially since I tried my best to avoid the use of Promises at all.

Edit: I used --trace-warnings .load to see what was going on (I reinstalled node) and apparently the promise in question (I'm guessing the one that contacts the discord API) is left with a `<pending>` value, for whatever reason.

Comment: Solved: the issue had to do with my own internet settings. The firewall and DNS were configured wrong, and after I fixed that the bot came online. Hope this helps if someone's having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem as OP, but the error looked different in node v15:

```
Uncaught Rejection (undefined): Error: unable to get local issuer certificate
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1518:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:376:20)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:942:8)
    at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:716:12)
ERROR: Unhandled rejection!
```

Came here to post the stack trace in case it helps someone else. (Similar to OP, the problem ended up being my VPN.)